# How import Feeds into entityforms

Tags: feeds, entities, importing-exporting

Does anyone know if there is a way to use `Feeds` to import into `Entityforms`?
 I have a `CSV` file of usernames and spent some hours at a specific event and would like to import it into it's corresponding form rather than entering it in all by hand.
**How can I import Data from `CSV` file into EntityForm`?**

Comment: Plz include drupal version

Answer (score 1):

Other than Migrate (which I have not tried yet), the only thing I have found was to use Feeds Import with the contributed patch for a Generic Entity Processor to import Entityforms.

https://drupal.org/node/1033202#comment-7710367

I currently have Drupal 7.23 and Feeds 7.x-2.x-dev (7/6/13) and I patched the feeds module successfully with the patch at comment #217.  This then gives you the option of having an entityform as a bundle.

I created a test entityform, a small test csv, and a new test feeds import.  The import completes successfully, but there's no content in the submissions.  Maybe you'll have better luck than I.  My next step is to checkout the latest from git and try again.  If that doesn't work, I guess I'm going to have to learn how to write a migrate module.

FYI, I have successfully used the Feeds Import module using the node processor that comes with the module for custom content types if you don't need it as an entityform.  There are several good Feeds videos out there is you're not familiar with the module.

Please reply if you find something else that works.

Comment: I've used Feeds to import into other nodes but did need it to import into an entityform.  Not much of a solution but, I ended up doing it by hand :(

Answer (score 1):

Both in D8 and 7 you can also use RESTful-interface:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2405657

You can POST to /entity/taxonomy_vocabulary etc

Answer (score 1):

To get around this, I set up an extra content type that and used [Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock).

It depends on your needs but for me, it offered the same functionality.